# How to make bagof give only one solution?

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicats:

```
color(ball,red).
color(ball,green).
color(book,red).
color(cube,green).
color(cup,red).
color(cube,yellow).
color(ball,yellow).
color(cube,pink).
```

I have to create a predicate where I have to use `bagof` in order to create a list with all the objects of which color is `@<` than a given atom. Something like: `solve(+At, -L)`.

I have tried `solve(At, L) :- bagof(X, (C^color(X, C), C @< At), L).`, but there would be more than one solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `C^` is misplaced. Should be `bagof(X, C^(color(X, C), C @< At), L).` Please show an example query and the multiple solutions you're referring to. Do you mean duplicates? Multiple lists?

Comment: @lurker Thanks. That's what I wanted. You can type your answer again in the comments to approve it.